# Insert text anywhere in Windows. (Like AutoText / Intellisense)

Tags: c#, text, autocomplete, accessibility

I'm creating a small accessibility feature (C#) that has to help users to insert bits of text anywhere within Windows. Something similar to the AutoText feature in Word or Intellisense in Visual Studio. So, whether typing an email in Outlook, a note in OneNote or a comment on Facebook (with whatever browser).

When the user types the first 3 letters of a known word or sentence, i want to present some kind of popup that they can use to complete the word/sentence.

I'm already detecting what the users are typing and that input is also being matched with the list of words in the autocomplete list. 
But now i need to know, how to insert the text that is found at the position of the cursor? (while the user is in whatever program..)
And something that would be really nice to have is that if this new piece of text could replace what has already been typed. That way i could have the users type "nhw" and it would be replaced by "need help with ".

Many thanks for you help, 
Tys

Comment: did you ever figure out the part about presenting some kind of popup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use `SendKeys()`.  See [How to: Simulate Mouse and Keyboard Events in Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171548.aspx).

To replace "nhw" with "need help with " you'll want to send `+({LEFT 3})need help with` to select "nhw" (Shift+Left/Left/Left) before typing "need help with ".

Comment: It took me another 10 minutes to find out about some special keys, so i thought i'd add it to this post. If you need combo's like CTRL+SHIFT+B you need these special chars:
! = ALT-key 
+ = SHIFT 
^ = CTRL

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to re-invent the wheel, you might want to check out [PhraseExpress](http://www.phraseexpress.com), which has [this feature](http://www.phraseexpress.com/autocomplete.htm).

Works in any program and is free for personal use.

It supports `SendKey()`, `VK_Packet` and `WMChar` as text insertion methods.